# Verificar si un Punto esta dentro de un cuadrilátero

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si un punto esta dentro o fuera de un cuadrado

> Un punto posee de 2 atributos, posiciones en 'X' y 'Y'.
>
> Un cuadrado posee de 4 atributos la posicion  X,Y, base, altura.

como se puede saber si el punto esta dentro o fuera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber si un Punto esta dentro de un cuadrado se debe comprobar lo siguiente:

> que el xPunto sea mayor al xcuadrado y que el xPunto sea menor al
>   xCuadrado+base
>
> que el yPunto sea mayor al ycuadrado y que el yPunto sea menor al
>   yCuadrado+altura

En el siguiente ejemplo compruebo con 2 puntos para los dos casos(punto dentro del cuadrado y el caso contrario).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var point = {
  'x': 2,
  'y': 20
};
var point2 = {
  'x': 20,
  'y': 20
};

var cuadrado = {
  'x': 10,
  'y': 10,
  'base': 50,
  'altura': 100
};


function putPixel(ctx, x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 2, 2);
}

function draw(x, y, base, altura) {
  ctx.strokeRect(x, y, base, altura);
}

draw(cuadrado.x, cuadrado.y, cuadrado.base, cuadrado.altura);
putPixel(ctx, point.x, point.y, 'blue');
putPixel(ctx, point2.x, point2.y, 'red');
console.log(comprobar(point, cuadrado));
console.log(comprobar(point2, cuadrado));

function comprobar(punto, cuadrado) {
  if (punto.x > cuadrado.x && punto.x < cuadrado.x + cuadrado.base && punto.y > cuadrado.y && punto.y < cuadrado.y + cuadrado.altura) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consideras que si está tocando la frontera está dentro o fuera? Esto es importante en el momento de saber si es < o <= lo que quieres coger como dentro o fuera.

Para empezar, en un cuadrado se cumple:

```
base == altura
```

Entonces asumo que estás hablando de un cuadrilátero cualquiera, un rectángulo.

A X le sumas la base y obtienes X+b.
A Y le sumas la altura y obtienes Y+a.

Tienes que explicar bien y conocer 1. Tu sistema de coordenadas, hacia dónde se incrementa el valor de X e Y? hacia la derecha y arriba? hacia derecha y abajo? Porque el signo de las operaciones tiene que ver con esto.

Generalmente, el punto (x1, y1) estará dentro del cuadrado si se cumple: (considerando que el punto sobre la frontera está incluído en el cuadrado)

```
(x1 <= X+b) AND (x1 >= X) AND (y1 <= Y+a) AND (y1 >= Y)
```

Y considerando que el punto sobre la frontera NO está incluído en el cuadrado:

```
(x1 < X+b) AND (x1 > X) AND (y1 < Y+a) AND (y1 > Y)
```

Pero debes tener en cuenta tu sistema de coordenadas.

Un saludo